# Binding Width to sum of actualWidths' of two elements in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make imitation of Datagrid with multilevel(2 level) column header. I am going to define first level with Grid on top of datagrid and the second level will be datagrid header itself as shown below:

[image]

The problem I have now (Which is probably in valueconventer) is that I want the width of `GridColumn1` always to be sum of widths' of `DataGridColumn1` and `DataGridColumn2` columns. For this, I have created value converter:

```
public class DataGridExtraHeaderConventer : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int actualWidth = 0;

            foreach (var item in values)
            {
                actualWidth += System.Convert.ToInt32(item);
            }

            return actualWidth;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var x = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            var y = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            return new object[] { x, y };
        }
    }
```

And Defined the `GridColumn1` as shown below:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition.Width>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DataGridExtraHeaderConventer }">
                            <Binding ElementName="Column1" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                            <Binding ElementName="Column2" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </ColumnDefinition.Width>
                </ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
```

`Datagrid` looks like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="datagrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="3" RowHeaderWidth="10">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column1" Binding="{Binding something}" Header="column 1" Width="50*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column2" Binding="{Binding something}"  Header="column 2" Width="60*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column3" Binding="{Binding something}" Header="column 3" Width="80" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column4" Binding="{Binding something}" Header="column 4" Width="*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

This code for some reason doesn't work. I run it successfully, buy the width of GridColumn is as it was without binding.

P.S If I want to bind `DataGridColumn1` column's width to `GridColumn1`, this works:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column1, Path=ActualWidth}">
```

Comment: You didn't state what your problem is. You just explained what you want to do and what you did do. However, note that ActualWidth is a floating point (double precision) value, which will cause rounding errors when you convert it to int's...

Comment: My code doesn't work and I want to find out why...

Comment: If you are saying that the (multi value) binding with your converter does not affect GridColumn1's width at all, then use the debugger and set a breakpoint on the DataGridExtraHeaderConventer.Convert method and see whether (A) it is actually being called, and whether (B) the values passed to the converter are actually what you expect, and (C) start single-stepping throught the converter code. I suspect your converter throws some exception (prime suspect being the call of Convert.ToInt32), preventing the binding to take effect; but only you can figure out the truth by doing some debugging

Comment: ok, I will try it now..

Comment: By the way, check the documentation for the type of `ColumnDefinition.Width` (it should also be provided in the `targetTypes` argument of your converter method). ColumnDefinition.Width's type is `GridLength` and your converter should preferably produce such an object (not sure if this is strictly necessary, as i am unable to verify/test this myself; but if you don't get closer to a solution, try returning a GridLength object)

Comment: I debug my code and every change of `DataGridColumn1` or `DataGridColumn2` calls convert method. Values are the widths' of `DataGridColumn1` and `DataGridColumn2`. There are no exceptions and the TargetType is `System.Windows.GridLength`

Comment: Okay. Then let your converter produce a GridLength object and see what happens...

Comment: Yes, returning `GridLength` solved the problem. Post answer below and I will mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converter in the question has two problems:

1. The values fed from the `ActualWidth` properties to the converter are of type `double`, but the converter converts them into integer values. This will cause rounding errors, causing the converter result to be somewhat inaccurate.
2. The `ColumnDefinition.Width` is of type `GridLength`. The *targetType* argument of the converter's *Convert* method will also tell this. Since a integer or floating point value is not implicitely/explictely convertible to *GridLength*, the converter itself has to produce and return such a *GridLength* object. Otherwise, the binding mechanism will reject the result produced by the converter.

Addressing the two issues, a working *Convert* method could look for example like this:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    try
    {
        double sumActualWidths = values.Sum(v => System.Convert.ToDouble(v));
        if (targetType == typeof(GridLength))
            return new GridLength(sumActualWidths);
        else
            return System.Convert.ChangeType(sumActualWidths, targetType);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Oops! Something went wrong.
        I better handle this exception in a meaningful way.

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```